# Feedback on special gun set of sfx

Tags: library-sound-effects, library, guns

Greetings all,

My team has created a gun sfx library recently. Here is the demo, but I do have something specific to ask:

http://soundcloud.com/funkyrustic/funky-rustic-gun-pack-demo

I use a technique I first really liked found in the game Half Life 2, specifically with the pistol. What made it unique was it's muted / gated initial plosive, followed by a baked in verb tail, augmented by verb based on location.

What are your thoughts on what we did in the library? And have any of you used this technique with your own sounds?

Thanks!

-Alex

http://www.funkyrustic.net

Answer (score 1):

I saw on your site that sounds are recorded at 44.1kHz 16 bits, most other libraries are in 96kHz 24 Bits... It's a huge difference when you are doing sound design, especially when you use pitch and time stretch effects.

Answer (score 0):

Well the demo sound file on soundcloud is a bit disappointing, in that it mostly contains someone talking about things I care little about. There's barely 10 actual sounds from the pack you hear, and that's not enough to decide to drop the $75 dollars for it.

That aside, I do know exactly the pistol sound you're talking about from Half Life 2, and even all those years ago it was very noticeable the difference between that and what other shooters had. I can definitely hear the influence, and it might be a nice thing to add to a collection for variation's sake.

Comment: Thanks much for the feedback Gaffe. What is it that you don't care about, exactly? Essentially it describes the set as to what's inside and provides a single example from each of the sounds. I'd be happy to send you more examples in a streamed file, but I'm sure you also understand the need to not give too much away for the potential of it being ripped.

We do have plans to preview all the sounds in a Unity demo with guns as well as how they're integrated. That's next year. :)

Thanks also for the feedback on the half life 2 set. I'm glad we included similar sounds in the lib!

-Alex

Comment: Perhaps it's just a personal thing, but when I want to know the specifics about whats in the pack, its after I've already listened to a demo of the samples and found myself interested, and then I read the accompanying text. The second I hit play on the file, and all I hear is a guy talking, I just want to skip through it hoping the second half is the actual samples, but then its just more talking. So then I have to sit through it to hear what I want to hear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to hit play and listen to samples and read the description while listening. I listened on an iPhone and I immediately skip the dialogue but when I do that I find myself landing on more explanations when I probably just skipped a quick sample. If your gonna keep the dialogue set up markers (which you can write descriptions on) on sound cloud so the listener has the option to jump right to the sound or can also listen to the discription if they wanted too, but my personal opinion.. it's not necessary. I also think the price is way too high for the quality of effect, also most mixers are prolly gonna wanna throw their own verb on especially guns, I get why you baked it in but I know mixers that hate that. I'd offer a dry version of each one as well, but for alot cheaper.